# Css selectors not working for simple jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a codeigniter that uses twitter bootstrap. At the end of it I have a simple fade in script using jquery:

```
<script src="http://localhost/b1/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>
```

the [HTML is here](http://pastebin.com/pHtgjJ6Z).

Now I copied the source from script code over from the page that it is working on to the one that is not working, and suspected 'content' is not declared on the non-working page.

to test this I ran $(".content").length; from the firebug console and the output is: 0 so apparently 'content' does not exist.

I want to pick another css selector to let the fade in script work, so I tried:

`$(".html").fadeIn(1000);` and  `$(".container").fadeIn(1000);`

It's still not working. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to pick a selector which will fade in the entire page?

I have portions of the page generated dynamically by php ( codeigniter ) . Specifically, the header, navbar and footer

Comment: Instead of pasting what works, why not show what doesn't work?  You can try doing `$("body").fadeIn(1000);` - but I'm not sure this is what you're after.

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/5uC9q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a div 'content' in your html so it is never going to find it....
Try doing it on body or html e.g `$(html).fadeIn(800)` - nb without the full stop at the start

Comment: I have portions of the page generated dynamically by php ( codeigniter ) . Specifically, the header, navbar and footer. does this matter?

Comment: try $('html').css('display','none'); $('html').fadeIn(800);

Comment: That does not work however I looked at the HTML for the page that does and that script acting on the 'content' selector looks like: <div class="content" style="display:none">, so you may be onto something

Comment: CORRECTION: it does work ( had pasted part of the code in the wrong place ). Would you mind explaining what you did there?

Comment: For an element (or page in this example) to be able to fade in it has to be hidden first. Previously the page was already displayed so there was nothing to fade in. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 5):

how about `$("body").fadeIn(1000)` for the whole page?  Note no dot since it's the element name, not a  class name.

Comment: I have portions of the page generated dynamically by php ( codeigniter ) . Specifically, the header, navbar and footer